# How to upload a lot of image through JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to upload 100 images through JMeter.
How can I load paths and names into JMeter's HTTP Request quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First use a CSV DataSet that will contain the paths of the list of files to send. Name variable to fileName
- Put images in bin folder of jmeter
- use Http Request and in field "Send files with the request" use ${fileName} , the right parameter name used by your upload form and the right mime type (you may add a column to csv for this). Set other fields of HTTP Requesf like path, host port to the right values
- In thread group configure 100 iterations

Run you test

Comment: Is it correct?
[CSV Data Set Config](http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0813/88/75ea97c3124688c643a44b5bd5ec3788.jpg)
[HTTP Request](http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0813/8e/3154930d5c34c9ecdf48232bff2c2b8e.jpg)
[CSV File](http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0813/7b/a993bfa88cddb65e81828fc06b44557b.jpg)

Comment: what you did seems correct but you may need to check in http sampler "Use multipart ..." also show thread group config, If ok you should accept and upvote